# Why does setInterval pickup the latest value of variable in nodejs, but fails to do so in React's useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-native, closures

NodeJS Code

```
let a = 0;

function useEffect(callback) {
  const b = callback;
  b();
}

const cb = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log('a', a);
  }, 1000);
};

useEffect(cb);

setInterval(() => {
  a++;
}, 500);
```

React's Code

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export const  App = ()=> {
    const [a, setA] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        console.log('a', a);
      }, 1000);
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        setA(a => a + 1)
      }, 500);
    }, [])

    return <></>
}
```

Results::
NodeJS: Updated value of a is logged after every interval
ReactJS: Logged value of a isn't updated in upcoming intervals

Shouldn't React's snippet execute similarly to nodejs, i.e. capture the reference of "a" and show the latest value. What am I missing here?

Comment: The difference is that in your first example, you only have a single `a` variable. But in your React example, you have **multiple** `a` variables, one for each call to your component function (each call to render the component). But your timer code only closes over the *first* of those, never seeing any of the others.

Comment: (It's nothing to do with Node.js vs. browser environment. Just how many `a` variables there are, what the closures over them are.)

Comment: You might use setTimeout function instead of setInterval

    const [a, setA] = useState(0);
      useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setA((a) => a+1);
        }, [1000])
        console.log(a);
      }, [a])